# Using "exec()" with NDK

Tags: android-ndk

I remember reading somewhere that it isn't advisable to use "exec" within the C code, compiled by NDK.

What is the recommended approach? Do we try and push the EXEC code up to the Java-space; that is, so the JNI (or application) spawns the new process, (and where relevant passes the results back down to the NDK)?

Comment: What is the command you would like to exec?  Is it a built-in system command or a native program included in your apk?

Answer (score 11):

First off, it's not recommended to use either `fork` or `exec`. All of your code is generally supposed to live in a single process which is your main Android application process, managed by the Android framework. Any other process is liable to get killed off by the system at any time (though in practice that doesn't happen in present Android versions as far as I have seen).

The rationale as I understand it is simply that the Android frameworks can't properly manage the lifetime and lifecycle of your app, if you go to spawn other processes.

### `Exec`

You have no real alternative here but to avoid launching other executables at all. That means you need to turn your executable code into a library which you link directly into your application and call using normal NDK function calls, triggered by JNI from the Java code.

### `Fork`

Is more difficult. If you really need a multi-process model, and want to fit within the letter of the rules, you need to arrange for the Android framework to fork you from its Zygote process. To do this, you should run all your background code in a different `Service` which is stated to run in a different process within the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

To take this to extremes, if you need multiple identical instances of the code running in different processes for memory protection and isolation reasons, you can do what Android Chrome does:

- Run all your background/forked code in a subclass of `Service`
- Create multiple subclasses of *that*
- List each of these subclasses as a separate service within your `AndroidManifest.xml` each with a different `process` attribute
- In your main code, remember exactly which services you've fired up and not, and manage them using `startService`/`stopService`.

Of course, if you've turned your native code into a library rather than an executable, you probably don't need `fork` anyway. The only remaining reason to use `fork` is to achieve memory protection/isolation.

### In practice

In practice quite a lot of apps ignore all this and use `fork`/`exec` within their native code directly. At the moment, it works, at least for short-running tasks.

Comment: So at the moment, rather than calling a separate process which we communicate via IPC --- we should rewrite the software so that it is threaded??

Comment: Yes, or even not threaded, just a bunch of synchronous function calls, of course.

Comment: This post was [linked](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128554619#comment4) as an almost official Android dev team position.