# Cannot run program "/data/user/0/xxx.xxxx.xx/files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: java, android

friends, when I want to export, a sub error occurs on my android 10 device and the phone freezes. I just couldn't figure it out.

I don't know what caused the error I added manifest - requestLegacyExternalStorage still not resolved.I get it when I start rendering in a video rendering application as an insert.

Part 1

```
 E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [/data/user/0/com.olustur.stickermaker/files/ffmpeg, -t, 10, -i, , -r, 30, -qscale:v, 5, /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.olustur.stickermaker/files/temp_intro_maker/temp_img%01d.jpg]
        java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.olustur.stickermaker/files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
            at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:15)
            at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.java:43)
            at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.java:12)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:389)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
         Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
            at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
            at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
            at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
            at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:15) 
            at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.java:43) 
            at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.java:12) 
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:389) 
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

Part 2

```
E/ACodec: [OMX.hisi.video.encoder.avc] failed to set output port definition parameters.
    [OMX.hisi.video.encoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -22
    signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -22)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xffffffea, actionCode 0, while in state 3
E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0xffffffea, resetting...
```

Part 3

```
E/Renderer: Movie generation FAILED
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2023)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1951)
    at eh.c(RenderEngine.java:74)
    at fh.e(Renderer.java:159)
    at fh$a.run(Renderer.java:75)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

Comment: i didnt any answer about error

Comment: I'm not sure what the previous comment means? ... Anyway, the `permission denied` error is causing an exception (the `java.io.IOException`), which is causing the crash. (or _freeze_, as you say) I don't know what is needed to give Android permission to use `ffmpeg`, but I would start there first.

Comment: See [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60370584/7644018) if it may be related. There are other questions having similar trouble as well.